# withLatestFrom using two Redux actions

Tags: rxjs, redux-observable

I have been trying to use rxjs properly with Redux observable and Redux actions. I've tried many different combinations of calling the below functions and every possible combination has given me different errors.

Basically, I have two actions that can be dispatched in my app: `SET_CIRCULAR_DATA` and `SET_MODAL_OVER_DEEP_LINK_FLAG`.

I'd like another action to be dispatched, `determineFoundInProducts()` when `SET_MODAL_OVER_DEEP_LINK_FLAG` happens followed by the first (successful) `SET_CIRCULAR_DATA` action. Any subsequent `SET_CIRCULAR_DATA` actions should be ignored until `SET_MODAL_OVER_DEEP_LINK_FLAG` happens again. Because of this need, I felt `withLatestFrom()` made the most sense. I also thought that `takeUntil()` and `repeat()` might be helpful to help me accomplish what I need, though I'm not including them in this code example because I'm stuck at the `withLatestFrom()` part.

I've tried different combinations of piping, not piping, using switchMap, map, mapTo, but nothing seems to work. I am importing all the used rxjs functions and I'm combining epics at the root, so it couldn't be that. I just can't seem to get the right combination to not get this to error.

Some examples of errors are

- Actions must be plain objects. Use custom middleware for async actions.
- You provided 'undefined' where a stream was expected

I am using RXJS ^5.5.6 and Redux Observable ^0.17.0.

```
import 'rxjs';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { withLatestFrom, map, tap, mergeMap } from 'rxjs/operators';
import ....all the types and actions

export const handleProductDetailsModalOnLoginRedirect = (action) =>
  action.ofType(weeklyAdTypes.types.SET_CIRCULAR_DATA).pipe(
    withLatestFrom(
      action.ofType(navigationTypes.types.SET_MODAL_OVER_DEEP_LINK_FLAG)
    ),
    mergeMap(([first, second]) => {
      console.log(first, second);
      return determineFoundInProducts();
    })
  );
```

### EDIT

I was struggling in my original post to determine what part of the code was breaking. What I had trouble with was that the redux observable action could not communicate with the rxjs functions. What I found was that piping appropriately piped (pun intended) the action to be workable with rxjs functions. Here is what I did.

```
action.ofType(navigationTypes.types.INIT_REDIRECT_MODAL_LOGIC)
  .switchMap(() =>
    action.ofType(weeklyAdTypes.types.SET_CIRCULAR_DATA)
    .withLatestFrom(action.ofType(navigationTypes.types.SET_MODAL_OVER_DEEP_LINK_FLAG))
      .take(1)
      .pipe(
        map(([first]) => {
         // Do stuff
         return determineFoundInProducts();
      }))
    )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The above answer will definitely help others. However, what I was struggling with was having redux observable action communicate with RXJS functions. Please see my edit to my original post for solution.

Answer (score 2):

The answer depends on what you want to happen if multiple `SET_MODAL_OVER_DEEP_LINK_FLAG` actions are dispatched before any `SET_CIRCULAR_DATA` action is, as well as whether they should some how be paired together with some sort of unique ID or not.

It sounds most likely like you're looking for `exhaustMap`.

The `exhaustMap` operator is basically the opposite behavior of `switchMap`. It maps inputs to inner observable and flattens its output, **ignore other input values until that observable completes.** It *exhausts* the inner Observable.

In your use case it means that we first listen for `SET_MODAL_OVER_DEEP_LINK_FLAG`, then we listen for a single `SET_CIRCULAR_DATA`, but while we're waiting for that subsequent `SET_CIRCULAR_DATA` we ignore all possibly incoming `SET_MODAL_OVER_DEEP_LINK_FLAG` actions. Note that the `take(1)` is important, because otherwise we'll listen for a stream of *every* `SET_CIRCULAR_DATA`, not just one.

```
export const handleProductDetailsModalOnLoginRedirect = (action) =>
  action.ofType(navigationTypes.types.SET_MODAL_OVER_DEEP_LINK_FLAG)
    .exhaustMap(() => 
      action.ofType(weeklyAdTypes.types.SET_CIRCULAR_DATA)
        .take(1)
        .map(() => determineFoundInProducts())
    );
```

---

Btw it's common to ask Redux Observable questions that are actually just RxJS questions. This is a cool thing to note because the RxJS community is **massive** so you'll find a TON more resources on it, as well as have a better chance of getting help if you're able to rephrase questions to be agnostic of Redux Observable--e.g. change `ofType('TYPE')` to a `filter(d => d.type === 'TYPE')`

Comment: Thanks for the help. This did help, though where I was stuck was the `action.ofType(weeklyAdTypes.types.SET_CIRCULAR_DATA)` not mapping. I needed to pipe the redux observable or else it would give me errors. I will update in my original posting.